# VSCODE Javascript ----how to Implicit import library

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I want to hide "import" when referencing the library, that is, local/global import, and use the contents of the library normally
Can it be achieved, or is it already achieved?

I use these codes in a plug-in loader, so I don’t need to import it. It’s just a tool for prompting to view annotations.

I am using VSCODE and its built-in JavaScript

example:

```
import { mc } from "./Libary/Game/Player";

mc.runcmd('kill u m')
```

want to use:

```
mc.runcmd('kill u m')
```

And you can also see comments and function types, etc.

Comment: Please note that ["Java" and "JavaScript" are related in name only](https://www.thesoftwareguild.com/faq/difference-between-java-and-javascript/).

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is achievable at the moment nor do I think it should be, because:

1. The imports are related to how modules in javascript language works
2. It may cause a lot of problems.

for example, imagine that you have two games like `Game1` and `Game2` which both of them has a `mc` method:

```
import { mc } from "./Libary/Game1/Player";
```

```
import { mc } from "./Libary/Game2/Player";
```

How should VScode decide what to import here?

but when you're using normal javascript imports it's just a matter of changing name imports like this:

```
import { mc as mc1 } from "./Libary/Game1/Player";
import { mc as mc2 } from "./Libary/Game2/Player";
```

Comment: Globally-defined variables are common in the JS ecosystem- the testing framework Jest is a popular example where functions like `describe` and `test` are loaded globally when `.test.ts` files are executed. With a `jsconfig.json` file, users of Jest are able to specify that the global functions of Jest will be available across their test files.
The question includes the detail `I use these codes in a plug-in loader`. This setup is similar to Jest since globals like `mc` are loaded before the scripts are run. The question use case is valid and jsconfig.json is the popular approach for VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring the API for your libraries in a `.d.ts` file and setting up a `jsconfig.json` in the root of your project, VSCode will automatically include those definitions in the global scope.

Here's an example repository with a functioning usage of `mc.runcmd`: https://github.dev/david-shortman/vscode-javascript-how-to-implicit-import-library

More information on declaration files- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html

More on `jsconfig.json`- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#using-tsconfigjson-or-jsconfigjson

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in vscode, this feature was introduced in one of the versions of IntelliJ IDEA but they had to roll back to the previous version within 2 weeks. It causes too much trouble for programmers. It became really hard to separate two programs from each other and apart from that the size of the build file keeps on increasing with every new project.
If you still want to do that use the idea shared by @David shortman